Устарелые опции -Xverify:none и noverify
Запуская Spring приложение, получаю warning:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Кроме того, не инициализируется контекст:
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Java\Projects\Quiz_Telegram_Bot\target\classes\ua\soros\telegram\App.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [D:\Java\Projects\Quiz_Telegram_Bot\target\classes\ua\soros\telegram\App.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
Гуглил опции JVM: -Xverify:none и -noverify - вообще никакой информации.
Смотрел список всех параметров в терминале:
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
В списке таких опций как -Xverify:none и -noverify тоже нет, возможно не туда копал.
Код запускаемой программы, возможно самый стандартный:
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Necessary code to start bot
        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}


См. EngSO: 64-Bit Server VM Warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13. Safe to delete -Xverify:none from Environment Variables?

Более критична проблема с запуском приложения -- сообщение Unsupported class file major version 60 указывает, что вы пытаетесь запустить на старой версии Java некий код (библиотеку), скомпилированный на Java 16.

Действительно, компиляция на 16-й, а в пропертях java.version - 14. Исправил версию на 17, теперь проект не собирается. При запуске класса App, сборка проекта топорится на Parsing java...

Сборка стопорится скорей всего из-за разных версий Java в системе. Пытался перейти полностью на jdk-23, скачал, установил переменные PATH и JAVA_HOME в 23-ю версию, всеравно java --version выдает openjdk 17. Как мне окончательно перейти на 23-ю jdk?

Вернулся к 17-й версии. Теперь ексепшен выглядит так: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Требуется больше подробностей о том, как собирается и запускается проект.

Опции JVM: -Xverify:none и -noverify тянула за собой зависимость telegram-spring-boot-starter от com.github.xabgesagtx версии 0.22. Также используемые версии библиотек Spring не поддерживается Java 17. Решением стало переход на Java 11.
